# How to center a textView in a tableViewCell?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a static tableView that I am creating like so....

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        usernameLabel.text = "Username"
        usernameDisplay.text = "placeholder"
        usernameDisplay.textColor = self.view.tintColor
        usernameLabel.frame = CGRect(x: self.view.bounds.minX, y: self.usernameCell.bounds.minY, width: self.view.frame.width, height: self.usernameCell.bounds.height)
        usernameDisplay.frame = CGRect(x: self.usernameCell.bounds.minX, y: self.usernameCell.bounds.minY, width: self.view.frame.width, height: self.usernameCell.bounds.height)
        usernameDisplay.textAlignment = .right
        usernameCell.addSubview(usernameLabel)
        usernameCell.addSubview(usernameDisplay)

        membershipTierLabel.text = "Membership Status"
        membershipTierDisplay.text = "Free (0-1GB)"
        membershipTierDisplay.textColor = self.view.tintColor
        membershipTierLabel.frame = CGRect(x: self.view.bounds.minX, y: self.membershipTierCell.bounds.minY, width: self.view.frame.width, height: self.membershipTierCell.bounds.height)
        membershipTierDisplay.frame = CGRect(x: self.view.bounds.minX, y: self.membershipTierCell.bounds.minY, width: self.view.frame.width, height: self.membershipTierCell.bounds.height)
        membershipTierDisplay.textAlignment = .right
        membershipTierCell.addSubview(membershipTierLabel)
        membershipTierCell.addSubview(membershipTierDisplay)

        dataUsedLabel.text = "Data Used"
        dataUsedDisplay.text = String(UserDefaults.standard.integer(forKey: "total_storage"))
        dataUsedDisplay.textColor = self.view.tintColor
        dataUsedLabel.frame = CGRect(x: self.view.bounds.minX, y: self.dataUsedCell.bounds.minY, width: self.view.frame.width, height: self.dataUsedCell.bounds.height)
        dataUsedDisplay.frame = CGRect(x: self.view.bounds.minX, y: self.membershipTierCell.bounds.minY, width: self.view.frame.width, height: self.membershipTierCell.bounds.height)
        dataUsedDisplay.textAlignment = .right
        dataUsedCell.addSubview(dataUsedLabel)
        dataUsedCell.addSubview(dataUsedDisplay)

        tipsText.text = "You can change the color of a progression tag by long-pressing it on the Progressions homepage"

        tipsText.frame = CGRect(x: tipsCell.bounds.minX,y: self.tipsCell.bounds.minY,width: tipsCell.bounds.width,height:self.tipsCell.bounds.height)
        //tipsText.textColor = UIColor.white
        //tipsText.textAlignment = .center
        tipsText.backgroundColor = self.view.tintColor
        tipsText.font = tipsText.font?.withSize(15)
        tipsText.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]

//        tipsText.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: tipsCell.centerYAnchor, constant:0).isActive = true
//        tipsText.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: tipsCell.centerXAnchor, constant:0).isActive = true
        //tipsText.textContainerInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 10, left: 5, bottom: 10, right: 5)
        tipsCell.backgroundColor = self.view.tintColor
        tipsCell.addSubview(tipsText)
        tipsText.center = CGPoint(x: tipsCell.bounds.midX, y: tipsCell.bounds.midY)

        feedbackText.text = "Feedback is loved! Please email with any issues, comments, ideas, or concerns"
        feedbackText.frame = CGRect(x: self.feedbackCell.bounds.minX,y: self.feedbackCell.bounds.minY,width: self.feedbackCell.bounds.width,height:self.feedbackCell.bounds.height)
        feedbackText.font = feedbackText.font?.withSize(15)
        feedbackCell.addSubview(feedbackText)

        //let bytes = UserDefaults.standard.integer(forKey: "total_storage")
        //storageAmount.text = format(bytes:Double(bytes))
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        //myTableView.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "MyCell")
        myTableView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.bounds.width, height: self.view.bounds.height)
        myTableView.dataSource = self
        myTableView.delegate = self
        self.view.addSubview(myTableView)
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        if indexPath.section != 0 {
            return 100
        } else {
            return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
        }
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        switch(section) {
        case 0: return 3    // section 0 has 2 rows
        case 1: return 1
        case 2: return 1// section 1 has 1 row
        default: fatalError("Unknown number of sections")
        }
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        switch(indexPath.section) {
        case 0:
            switch(indexPath.row){
            case 0:
                print("username")
                return self.usernameCell
            case 1:
                return self.membershipTierCell
            case 2:
                return self.dataUsedCell
            default: fatalError("Unknown row")
            }
        case 1:
            switch(indexPath.row){
            case 0:
                return self.tipsCell
            default: fatalError("Unknown row")
            }
        case 2:
            print("feedback")
            switch(indexPath.row){
            case 0:
                print("feedback")
                return self.feedbackCell
            default: fatalError("Unknown row")
            }
        default: fatalError("Unknown section")
        }
    }
}
```

Right now it looks like [image]

As you can see I am trying to set the tipsText (UITextView) in the exact center of the tipsCell using: `tipsText.center = CGPoint(x: tipsCell.bounds.midX, y: tipsCell.bounds.midY)`

As you can see, this isn't working as the tipsText is still on the top of the tipsCell. How can I center it like I want here?

Comment: Can you try to add .flexibleTopMargin, .flexibleBottomMargin, .flexibleLeftMargin, and .flexibleRightMargin to tipsText's autoresizingMask?

Comment: Is there any reason you're not doing this in a storyboard?

Comment: Or override viewWillLayoutSubviews and set the subview's frame there.

Comment: @Adrian I couldn't figure out how to tie the dynamic labels into IBOutlets. It seems you had to make a container view and embed a custom tableviewcontroller into that to make it show up. So I ended up trying to do it programatically like this.

Comment: @BigBoy1337 What happened on this?

Comment: @Adrian sorry I can't find your answer. Do you have a link to the repo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have two ways to fulfill your wish.

One way is to set the heights of tipsCell and feedBackCell to 100 in IB if you have.

The other way is to add the codes as the following:

```
 tipsText.textAlignment = .center
    tipsText.numberOfLines = 0
    tipsText.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]

  feedbackText.textAlignment = .center
   feedbackText.numberOfLines = 0
     feedbackText.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
```

Hopefully it is helpful.

If it is TextView, you may get estimated frames like this:

```
    tipsText.textContainer.maximumNumberOfLines = 0
    tipsText.textContainer.heightTracksTextView = true
    tipsText.attributedText = NSAttributedString.init(string:  "You can change the color of a progression tag by long-pressing it on the Progressions", attributes: [NSAttributedString.Key.font : UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 15) ])
    tipsText.textAlignment = .center
    let size = tipsText.textContainer.size
    tipsText.frame = CGRect(x: tipsCell.bounds.minX,y: self.tipsCell.bounds.minY,width: tipsCell.bounds.width,  height :size.height )
    tipsText.backgroundColor = self.view.tintColor
    tipsText.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
    tipsCell.backgroundColor = self.view.tintColor
    tipsCell.addSubview(tipsText)
    tipsText.center = CGPoint(x: tipsCell.bounds.midX, y: tipsCell.bounds.midY)


    feedbackText.textContainer.maximumNumberOfLines = 0
    feedbackText.textContainer.heightTracksTextView = true
    feedbackText.attributedText = NSAttributedString.init(string:  "Feedback is loved! Please email with any issues, comments, ideas, or concerns", attributes: [NSAttributedString.Key.font : UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 15) ])
    feedbackText.textAlignment = .justified
    let feedbackSize = feedbackText.textContainer.size
    feedbackText.frame = CGRect(x: feedbackCell.bounds.minX,y: self.feedbackCell.bounds.minY,width: feedbackCell.bounds.width,  height :feedbackSize.height )
    feedbackText.backgroundColor = self.view.tintColor
    feedbackText.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
    feedbackCell.backgroundColor = self.view.tintColor
    feedbackCell.addSubview(feedbackText)
    feedbackText.center = CGPoint(x: feedbackCell.bounds.midX, y: feedbackCell.bounds.midY)
```

Comment: hmm no luck with this one either. The UITextView is still at the top. Also TipsText is a UITextView which does not have the numberOfLines property. Perhaps you are thinking of UILabel? Finally I am not using IBOutlets. I couldn't figure out a good way to make a tableView with IBOutlets so I made one programatically.

Comment: ah but actually it works when I change the UITextView to a UILabel and try your code. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I assume you know how to use custom view classes.
There a custom class for UITextView;

```
class VerticallyCenteredTextView: UITextView {
    override var contentSize: CGSize {
        didSet {
            var topCorrection = (bounds.size.height - contentSize.height * zoomScale) / 2.0
            topCorrection = max(0, topCorrection)
            contentInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: topCorrection, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: hmm no luck with this one. The textView (now VerticallyCenteredTextView) is still up at the top.